# Derivative chain rule in a triangle, confusing but interesting problem

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I asked the question in math.stackexchange. But I think it is better to ask here again. I am new to these sites. Please forgive me if it is not polite.
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921001
You can reply any poster. I paste it again here.

[image: variables in triangle]
Refer to the above figure. Assuming the length of the 3 edges of triangle are $r_0,z_0,\xi_0$. And we have $\xi=\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$ (Eqn.1)and $\xi_0=\sqrt{r_0^2+z_0^2}$. The normal vector on the hypotenuse is $\hat{n}$, and the components are $n_r=\frac{z_0}{\xi_0}$ and $n_z=-\frac{r_0}{\xi_0}$
Meanwile$\frac{\xi}{r}=\frac{\xi_0}{r_0}=\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$(Eqn.2) and $\frac{\xi}{z}=\frac{\xi_0}{z_0}=\frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}$(Eqn.3).

Now I have a funtion $T=T(r,z)$ on the hypotenuse, and I need to calculate $f=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{z}}n_r-\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{r}}n_z=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{z}}n_r-\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{r}}n_z$ (Eqn.4)

If using Eqn.1, then $\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{z}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}$ (Eqn.1*a)and $\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}$(Eqn.1*b)
and

$f=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}(\frac{z_0z}{\xi_0\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}+\frac{r_0r}{\xi_0\sqrt{r^2+z^2}})$. (Eqn.5)

If using Eqn.2 and Eqn.3, $\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{\xi_0}{z_0}$ (Eqn.6)and$\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\xi_0}{r_0}$(Eqn.7)
and

$f=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}(\frac{\xi_0z_0}{z_0\xi_0}+\frac{\xi_0r_0}{r_0\xi_0})=2\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}$(Eqn.8)

It looks to me that Eqn.6 and Eqn.7 are right. but Eqn.8 is wrong. because when $\theta$ goes to 90degree,it should be $f=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{\xi}}$

So what is the right expression for $f$, and why?

($f$ is azimuthal component of the $\nabla\times({T\hat{n}})$) as somebody asked.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a mistake in Eq.4.  Your function $T(r,z)$ does not depend on $\xi$ and has nothing in principle to do with triangles.  Since you are only interested in values of $T$ for $(r,z)$ pairs that satisfy Eq.1, you could write $T$ as a function of $r$ and $\xi$, OR as function of $z$ and $\xi$.  However, until you do, the partial derivative of $T$ with respect to $\xi$ looks to me to be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your consideration. $\xi$ is the length variable along the triangle hypotenuse.$\xi$ is surely function of $z$ and $r$. Although Eqn.1 & Eqn.2-3 are right,but $f$ as Eqn.8 should be wrong, but I don't know why. For Eqn.5,it is correct when $\theta=\pi/2$ , but I still don't know if it is right or not.

Comment: some updates please see the (hidden) comments in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/921001. But still don't know why.

Comment: I think this is very important/essential concept of partial derivative in triangle. Need your help!!!